# Perl max execution time on webserver

Tags: php, perl, time, webserver

How can I set the execution time of a perl skript on a webserver. Is this analog to php in the php.ini "max_execution_time" or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a CGI (not mod_perl or FastCGI), it may be worthwhile just adding the following towards the top of the code:

```
alarm 30; # SIGALRM delivered to this process after 30 secs
```

If the program has no handler for SIGALRM, it will die.

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
alarm 2;
my $n = 0;
while ( 1 ) {
  print "$n\n";
  sleep 1;
  $n++;
}
__END__
$ perl alr
0
1
Alarm clock
```

You can choose what should happen when the timeout occurs, like this:

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
  # do stuff
};
```

You would place that code before you use the alarm().

An example there could be sending an e-mail to advise you the script took longer than expected, or whatever.

Alarms can also be used as watchdogs for specific sections of the code, like:

```
alarm 5;    # shouldn't take longer than 5 seconds. if not, die.
do_stuff();
alarm 0;    # reset the alarm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I know what you mean.

But what if I use mod_perl for apache. Where can I set the max execution time like in PHP. Does anyone knows it for example for (l)xammp?

Comment: You can do the same thing as above, only under mod_perl it will kill the Apache child rather that just the CGI.
Under mod_perl. you can use something like:
PerlSetEnv PERL_RLIMIT_CPU 120. Look at mod_perl docs for that!